# ORA-00904: "DUMMYFLAG": invalid identifier when use exp utility

Tags: oracle, export

i wanted to export table using exp utility,

The server oracle version is 11.2.0.3.0

```
client1 version is "10.2.0.1.0", from here, it has exported with no problem.
client2 version is "11.2.0.1.0", from here, it has error
```

The error is

```
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 904 encountered
ORA-00904: "DUMMYFLAG": invalid identifier
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

, it looks like if table has partition then it shows above error,
and if table has no partition then it exported without error.

From client1, there is no error for both with partition and without partition.

Would you please suggest me any clue ? What happening here exactly ?

Comment: Check this link - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:478275606639

Comment: Thanks Pravin Satav, actaully i googled it a lot , but couldn't get right answer , checked this link also, my client machines are windows 2008 and 64 bit, oracle server is linux machine, am also using par file on both. I think my problem is related with DummyFlag , so couldn't find about dummyflag on oracle.

Comment: Can you share your export and import script?

Comment: Okay, My par file content is  : log=D:\....\sett.log
file=D:\...\sett.dmp
userid=userid/password
tables=(
user.table:partition
)
compress=yes
consistent=no
indexes=yes
rows=yes   and my bat file content is @echo off
exp parfile=D:\...\test.par  ,  and i did not try the imp utility.